# Detecting what folders to upload to a live Drupal 7 site after changes?

Tags: upload, migration, drupal-7, drupal-modules, production-environment

I haven't yet setup version control (GIT) for my development and production environments as a result I am facing trouble syncing everything. My site is powered by Drupal 7.

For example, for a Content type that I created, what exactly is the folder on my development site that I should be uploading. And as far as the content type I created, what folder should I be uploading to the live server?

Another case is where I make changes to 'Text formats' found in admin -> configuration and a couple of other places in admin -> configuration, well, Not sure what folder I should be uploading either.

Thanks much people!

P.S: Feel free to give me some slack for not setting up GIT or version control, lesson learnt but for now I need to get this uploaded

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to upload any files/folders for the situations you've described, all content type and text format data is stored in the database.

Content type data is stored in the `node_type` table, and text formats are stored in the `filter_format` table.

Further data relating to both are stored in the `variables` table as serialised strings.

Hope that helps

Comment: well then how do you sync between development and production environment in case of drupal without having to push everything online everytime something is updated? -Thanks

Comment: @ParijatKalia: I use [Navicat for MySQL](http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_mysql/mysql_overview.html), it has an in-built data-sync tool which works a treat.